# kill Thread in android

Tags: android, multithreading, session, timer

I work on my graduation project and really need the assistant.
After multiple attempts and research I could not find a solution to my problem.
I would like to set a time to log out after 15 minutes.
I did that but I had a problem I could not kill the thread. Even when logged out, the Thread continues to work. For example, if I logged out and then log in and the remaining of 15 minutes are 4 minutes then my login will continue for 4 minutes instead of 15 minutes.

I want to restart the Thread when logging in again

```
     Thread thread=new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
      while (!isInterrupted()){
          try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                      counter++;
                      if(counter==10){

                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            MainActivity.this.finish();

                      }
                  }
              });
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
    }
};
thread.start();
```

}

I hope you really help

Comment: Have a look at [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which has all the features you need.

Comment: You're catching the `InterruptedException` and its status flag is automatically reset this : `!isInterrupted()` will be satisfied every time in your while loop (unless you happen by chance to interrupt whilst the Thread is NOT sleeping). You need to set the flag again in the `catch` block - `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` then on next iteration it will drop out of the while loop and the `Thread` will naturally finish it's work.  Obviously you need to call `thread.interrupt` in the first place as well.